# Initial value problem - How can we find the coefficients $c_j$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the initial value problem $$u'(t)=Au(t) \ \ , \ \ 0 \leq t \leq T \\ u(0)=u^0 \\ u \in \mathbb{R}^m$$ A is a $m \times m$ matrix

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_j$ and the corresponding eigenvectors are $\phi^{(j)}$.

The general solution of initial value problem is $$u(t)=\sum_{j=1}^m c_j e^{\lambda_jt}\phi^{(j)}$$

right??

For $t=0$ we have $$u^0=\sum_{j=1}^m c_j \phi^{(j)}$$ How can we solve for $c_j$ ??

Comment: $u(t)$  is the general solution if the $\lambda_j$ are distinct (not otherwise). Your equation for $c_j$ is of the form b = Bc where c is a vector of $c_j$ values and B is a matrix.

Comment: But how is the equation of this form?? We have a sum... @Paul

Comment: You mean when we have done the multiplication $B \cdot c$ ?? @Paul

Comment: i assume that $\{\phi_1, \phi_2, \cdots, \phi_n\}$ is a basis of $R^n.$  in that case you solve the matrix equation $u_0 = \Phi c$ where the columns of $\Phi$ are $\phi_1, \phi_2, \cdots, \phi_n.$

Comment: are the $\lambda_j$ distinct?

Comment: Yes, the $\lambda_j$ are distinct. @robjohn

Comment: So, do we write the following?? $$c=u_0\Phi^{-1}$$ But $c$ is a vector, right?? Which is the formula of $c_j$?? @abel

Comment: @MaryStar, did you mean $c = \Phi^{-1} u_0?$

Comment: Oh, yes... That's what I meant... @abel

Comment: But is there a general formula for $c_j$. I found my in notes that thw coefficienrs are $(u^0, \phi^{(j)})$. How have we find it?? @abel

Comment: that means $\{\phi_1, \phi_2, \cdots, \phi_n\}$is an orthonormal set. that is $\langle \phi_i, \phi_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$

Comment: Is the set of the eigenvectors always an orthonormal set?? @abel

Comment: they can be made either if the eigenvalues are all distinct or if the matrix is symmetric. more generally, if the matrix is normal that is $AA^\top = A^\top A,$  then $A$ has an orthonormal eigenbasis.